# wsdl2 does not show extended functions in ColdFusion 10

Tags: soap, coldfusion, wsdl, apache-axis, coldfusion-10

I have a simple test setup:

```
component displayname="test1" extends="test2"
{
    remote Any function ping1() {}
}

component displayname="test2"
{
    remote Any function ping2() {}
}
```

When I cal the cfc using `test1.cfc?wsdl` something strange happens.

When I tell my application to use WSDL version 1 using `this.wssettings.version` everything looks fine, pretty much the same as in CF9. But when I tell it to use version 2 the function "ping2" does not show up in my definition xml.

Why doesn't WSDL 2 show my extended function "test2" when I call `test1.cfc?wsdl` ??

Comment: Racking my brain but can't think of any reason why this would be - especially if both ping1 and ping2 are set remote. any other details? what are the _actual_ names of your functions Jan?

Comment: The code above _is_ the actual code. It happens using this simple code!

Answer (score 3):

I tried this on ColdFusion 10 and both WSDL and WSDL2 do not show the inherited methods.  I only see the ping1() function of the test1.cfc, I do not see ping2() inherited from test2.cfc. If you change the "Select web service version" value in the ColdFusion Administrator from 2 (the default) to 1, then ColdFusion 10 performs as ColdFusion 9 does and shows both methods.

On ColdFusion 9, the WSDL shows both methods.

In my opinion, this is a bug in ColdFusion 10, you should log it with Adobe (https://bugbase.adobe.com/), and post the bug number here so others can vote for it.  This could break existing functionality if people upgrade without changing the default web services version.

Comment: Good point! I did submit the bug at Adobe so here it is: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3197933

Answer (score 0):

I tried this exact code on CF 9.01 and did not get the same result. My WSDL shows both methods. Something is unique about your CF install - perhaps the wrong version of Axis or something?  I'm sorry I can't be more helpful - but I'm struggling to figure out a way to duplicate your issue.

Comment: Yes, I got the same. WSDL 1 works just fine in CF9 and CF10 but WSDL 2 in CF10 is the problem here.

Comment: Try it on CF10 (any version) and run `test1.cfc?wsdl2`. You will see what I mean.